# React - Change Style when accessing event target

Tags: reactjs

I am using "**`React Sortable Hoc`**" npm lib for sorting elements by dragging.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sortable-hoc

One of the events I am using is built in **`onSortMove`** which returns event.

I can access the style of this element by **`event.target.style`**

And if I try to set new style property element is not change it is style or simple I just can not print new value.

```
onSortMove = (event, index, collection) =>
    {
        // changing of style - I think it should work?
        event.target.style.cursor = 'grabbing';

        // checek if style is changed, but it is not. Why?
        console.log(event.target.style);
    };
```

Comment: use  '-webkit-grabbing' or 'move' ?

Comment: property style is not changed in react element. I can not show changed value in the console. This is the main problem.